# Shopify Order Fulfill Api Returning 404 Error

Tags: shopify, fulfillment

We are using shopify fulfillment api. But it always returning 404 error

Below is the first API call

Get : https://www.shopename.co.nz/admin/api/2024-01/orders/5314690416794/fulfillment_orders.json

Result :

`{ "fulfillment_orders": [ { "id": 6318300135578, "shop_id": 42717151386, "order_id": 5314690416794, "assigned_location_id": 49693130906, "request_status": "unsubmitted", "status": "open", "supported_actions": [ "create_fulfillment", "hold" ], "destination": { "id": 5887302697114, "address1": "81 Devon Street", "address2": null, "city": "Arrowtown", "company": "TEST", "country": "New Zealand", "email": "email", "first_name": "first_name", "last_name": "last_name", "phone": null, "province": "Otago", "zip": "9302" }, "line_items": [ { "id": 13008511500442, "shop_id": 42717151386, "fulfillment_order_id": 6318300135578, "quantity": 1, "line_item_id": 12828296249498, "inventory_item_id": 41957326356634, "fulfillable_quantity": 1, "variant_id": 39862384459930 } ], "international_duties": null, "fulfill_at": "2024-03-05T16:00:00+13:00", "fulfill_by": null, "fulfillment_holds": [], "created_at": "2024-03-05T16:42:51+13:00", "updated_at": "2024-03-05T16:42:51+13:00", "delivery_method": { "id": 783803383962, "method_type": "shipping", "min_delivery_date_time": null, "max_delivery_date_time": null }, "assigned_location": { "address1": "10/50 Buckingham Street", "address2": "", "city": "Arrowtown", "country_code": "NZ", "location_id": 49693130906, "name": "10/50 Buckingham Street", "province": "Otago", "zip": "9302" }, "merchant_requests": [] } ] }`

Below is the Fulfillment API call

POST : https://www.shopename.co.nz/admin/api/2024-01/fulfillments.json

Payload :
`{ "fulfillment": { "message": null, "notify_customer": false, "location_id": 49693130906, "tracking_info": { "number": "TEST0000001", "url": "url", "company": "XXX" }, "line_items_by_fulfillment_order": [ { "fulfillment_order_id": 6318300135578, "fulfillment_order_line_items": [ { "id": 13008511500442, "quantity": 1 } ] } ] } }`

Result :
`{ "errors": "Not Found" }`

Below access scopes are also added
write_assigned_fulfillment_orders,read_assigned_fulfillment_orders,write_fulfillments,read_fulfillments,write_merchant_managed_fulfillment_orders,read_merchant_managed_fulfillment_orders,write_orders,read_orders,write_products,read_products,write_third_party_fulfillment_orders,read_third_party_fulfillment_orders,write_custom_fulfillment_services,read_custom_fulfillment_services,read_all_orders

Please help us to find out the exact issue

It is expected to get 201 or 200 status code as return